# QGIS: Making changes to vector layers stored in PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a vector layer stored in PostGIS. I split several lines in the layer and simplified others by removing vertices.

When I tried to save the changes to the layer I got postgres more postgres errors about duplicate gids.

Is this a result splitting features and if so how do I get around the issue?

Russell

Answer (score 2):

Ah, trap for young players (or perhaps that should be new players ;)

After more poking around I realised that while cut and pasting line segments between layers on occasions I had forgotten to select the new layer before pasting and thereby duplicating the feature in the original layer.  Hence the duplicate gids.